# Docusign - Transform PDF text field to initialHereTab

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is it possible to transform **PDF text field** (not signature field) to initialHereTab ?

*Note : it works well with signature field but not with text filed*

Here is my JSON request:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "PDFDocumentInBase64",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Merge_2020310203633868.pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "clientUserId": "1",
                "email": "myEmail@email.ca",
                "name": "Paul J Smith",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "initialHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "\\applicant1\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Please sign this legal form at your convenience",
  "status": "created"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, per the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/tabs#pdftransform):

> If: Adobe name contains DocuSignInitialHere or eSignInitialHere
>
> Then: a DocuSign Initials tab will be created

Comment: I don't want to use DocuSignInitialHere pattern because I have multiple recipients ...